# Crane optimize method

Tags: c#, .net, optimization

some of you might have the book (in my case the german) "Einstieg in Visual C# 2013" by Thomas Theis. In this book there is a exercise about programming a simple crane.

I would like to optimize my code by replacing the if else querys with one method, which is called in every method before anything else. if true = contine with code, if false = stop continuing and show an `errormessage` in the label and don't execute the rest of the code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Ükran
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private bool Kran = false;


        // Codeoptimierung: (optimize code)

        private void checkKranIstAn()
        {
            if(Kran == true)
            {
                lblAnzeige.Text = " ";
                return;
            } else
            {
                lblAnzeige.Text = "Der Kran wurde noch nicht angeschaltet! Bitte anschalten!";
                return;
            }

        }

        //method with if else statement that should be replaced
        private void cmdHakenRaus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Kran == true)
            {
                panel4.Size = new Size(panel4.Width = panel4.Width, panel4.Height = panel4.Height + 10);

            } else
            {
                lblAnzeige.Text = "Der Kran wurde noch nicht angeschaltet! Bitte anschalten!";
            }
        }

        //THIS! here i tried it but didnt know how to do it the right way
        private void cmdHakenRein_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            checkKranIstAn();
            panel4.Size = new Size(panel4.Width = panel4.Width, panel4.Height = panel4.Height - 10);
        }

        private void cmdAuslegerRaus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panel3.Location = new Point(panel3.Location.X - 10, panel3.Location.Y);
            panel4.Location = new Point(panel4.Location.X - 10, panel4.Location.Y);
            panel3.Size = new Size(panel3.Width = panel3.Width + 10, panel3.Height);
        }

        private void cmdAuslegerRein_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panel3.Location = new Point(panel3.Location.X + 10, panel3.Location.Y);
            panel4.Location = new Point(panel4.Location.X + 10, panel4.Location.Y);
            panel3.Size = new Size(panel3.Width = panel3.Width - 10, panel3.Height);
        }

        private void cmdKranRechts_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panel1.Location = new Point(panel1.Location.X - 10, panel1.Location.Y);
            panel2.Location = new Point(panel2.Location.X - 10, panel2.Location.Y);
            panel3.Location = new Point(panel3.Location.X - 10, panel3.Location.Y);
            panel4.Location = new Point(panel4.Location.X - 10, panel4.Location.Y);
        }

        private void cmdKranLinks_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panel1.Location = new Point(panel1.Location.X + 10, panel1.Location.Y);
            panel2.Location = new Point(panel2.Location.X + 10, panel2.Location.Y);
            panel3.Location = new Point(panel3.Location.X + 10, panel3.Location.Y);
            panel4.Location = new Point(panel4.Location.X + 10, panel4.Location.Y);
        }

        private void cmdKranAus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Kran = false;
        }

        private void cmdKranEin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Kran = true;
        }

        private void cmdEnde_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Aaaaaaaaaand what's your question?

Comment: Bit confused as to what you are trying to achieve? Are you just asking for us to optimise that method `checkKranIstAn`?

Comment: yes. I want to delete all this "if else" stuff and create one method called "checkKranIstOn" (check if the crane is enabled)

the other methods should then look like:

public void doSomething() {
checkKranIstAn();
doSomethingElse;
doSomethingEvil;
}
 if checkKranIstAn= false the rest (dosomethingelse and dosomethingevil) should not be executed.

Comment: Woooow. Votedown -3? Thanks. Why this happend?

Comment: I didn't, but usually, code reviews belongs to... [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) :)

Comment: thanks. votedown -4 now :( do i get punished if my stuff is voted down 2 much? or what does votedown do? 

btw sorry for offtopic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with:

```
private void checkKranIstAn()
{
    lblAnzeige.Text = kran ? " " : "Der Kran wurde noch nicht angeschaltet! Bitte anschalten!";
}
```

You skip the checking of `kran == true` which is useless, remove the `return` statement, which is useless too.

---

Or this pretty function:

```
private bool Kran()
{
    lblAnzeige.Text = " ";
    if(!kran)
    {
        lblAnzeige.Text = "Der Kran wurde noch nicht angeschaltet! Bitte anschalten!";
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

which is used:

```
private void cmdHakenRaus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Kran())
    {
        panel4.Size = new Size(panel4.Width = panel4.Width, panel4.Height = panel4.Height + 10);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a single if statement, have a look at the [?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) operator. The `return` statement is useless.

```
private void checkKranIstAn()
{
    lblAnzeige.Text = Kran ? string.Empty : "Der Kran wurde noch nicht angeschaltet! Bitte anschalten!"
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) helped me also a lot.